# xelatexmk in TexStudio/TexMaker

Tags: xetex, texstudio

In TexShop I can bring `xelatexmk` engine out from `~Library/TexShop/Engines/Inactive` folder to `~Library/TexShop/Engines` for using.
[image]

Is there a way to use `xelatexmk` in TexMaker or TexStudio?
In the Commands option of TexStudio I only find XeLaTeX.

[image]

Comment: `xelatexmk` is `latexmk` with `-xelatex` option! If you change the `-pdf` option to `-xelatex` in the line Latexmk, then you can use `latexmk` as `xelatexmk`.

Comment: @hair-splitter thank you very much, it works. Please make a separate post and I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xelatexmk` is `latexmk` with `-xelatex` option!
So, if you replace the `-pdf` option to `-xelatex` in the line Latexmk, then you can use `latexmk` as `xelatexmk`.

Or, you can make a user `xelatexmk` menu item:

- Options
- Configure TeXstudio
- Build
- User Commands: +Add
- Replace `user0:` to `xelatexmk` and type this in the box next to it:

`latexmk -xelatex -silent -synctex=1 %`

- OK

Then you can use the `xelatexmk` menu in the following way:

- Tools
- User
- xelatexmk

(or the keyboard shortcut: Alt+Shift+F1)